# Exponential distribution as model for purchasing airline tickets

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

I, again, have a statistics problem that I am totally clueless about how to solve it.

> On average, flight passengers purchase airplane tickets 15 days in advance. Assuming an exponential distribution:
>
> 1. What is the probability that a passenger buys her ticket ten days or less before departure?
> 2. How many days until departure do half of the passengers wait?

My problem in about part 2). I do have the supposed correct result here (which is 10.3972) but I have no idea how to approach it and Google doesn't show me any similar questions.

I know you guys always want to see how we ourself can solve it, but I really have no idea :(

Thanks a lot!

Comment: The question assumes you know what an exponential distribution is. Find out. It's probably in your textbook. Write the definition. Plug the mean of 15 into the distribution. Find the cumulative distribution function. Find where that function equals $\frac12.$ Whatever you try, actually write it in the question so we can see what you've done and what you understood. Also, use MathJax: https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation

Comment: In R statistical software `qexp(.5, 1/15)` returns 10.39721. The R function `qexp` is the inverse cdf, so this is the median of an exponential distribution with mean 15 (rate 1/15). Also, this is the same as 15 ln(2) of the Answer by @RichardAmbler,, which you should accept.

Answer (score 2):

The probability density function of the [exponential distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution) is:

$$f(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{rl}\lambda e^{-\lambda x},&x\ge0\\0,&x<0\end{array}\right.$$

To solve for the median number of days waited, which is what question 2 is after, we need to find $t$ in:

$$\begin{align}\int_0^tf(x)\;\text dx&=\frac 12\\\int_0^t\lambda e^{-\lambda x}\;\text dx&=\\-\left[e^{-\lambda x}\right]_0^t&=\\e^{-\lambda t}&=\frac 12\\-\lambda t&=-\ln 2\\t&=\frac{\ln 2}\lambda\end{align}$$

The expected value of the pdf is $\lambda^{-1}$ (which you can verify by evaluating $\displaystyle \int_{x\in X}x\ f(x)\;\text dx$). From the given information, $\lambda=\frac{1}{15}$. Substituting this in, we get the result $t=15\ln 2$.

Answer (score 1):

**Graphical comment:**  Here is a graph of the density function of the
distribution $\mathsf{Exp}(\mu = 15).$ The total area beneath the curve
is $1.$ The area to the left of the vertical dotted red line is the probability someone buys a ticket 15 days of less ahead of time. The vertical broken blue line is at the median; half of the area beneath the curve is on either side
of this line. So the figure illustrate both the mean (red) and median (blue) of this distribution. In such a right-skewed distribution, it is typical for the mean to be larger than the median.

[image]